# Datatables encode HTML

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have used [jQuery Datatables](http://datatables.net) on my Laravel web apps. I have used packagist `chumper/datatable` to handle Datatables server processing.

Unfortunately, I found serious security problem, i.e. XSS (cross-site scripting).
Server returns JSON data and Client loads the data to table without escaping them.

How can I get Client to escape the data before loading them into the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`fnCreatedRow`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnCreatedRow) is a callback function for manipulating table row element after the row has been created. We can used this callback function to modify the row before the row will be inserted to HTML document.

I used `chumper/datatable` to generate this function:

```
$table = Datatable::table()
    ->addColumn('ID', 'Username', 'Name', 'Email', 'Actions')
    ->setUrl(URL::to('admin/users/data'))
    ->setOptions(array('aoColumns' => array(array('sType' => 'numeric'), null, null, null, array('bSortable' => false))))
    ->setCallbacks('fnCreatedRow', 
        'function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
            for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) jQuery("td:eq(" + i + ")", nRow).text(aData[i]);
        }'
    )
    ->noScript();       
return View::make('admin.users.index', compact('table'));
```

I used `fnCreatedRow` to modify the content of each `td` elements so the `td` elements display the data as text (HTML encoded).